# Shell - Is *${i,,}* correct and what is it for?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am reviewing a shell script and found this lines :

```
DIR=/home/bot/REP_INV/
LIST=/root/ListeTRI.txt
...
ligne=`cat $LIST`
for i in $ligne
do
    /bin/cp  $DIR*$i* /root/$i/InvExt/
    /bin/cp  $DIR*${i,,}* /root/$i/InvExt/
done
```

In the DIR folder I have a large number of file and in the LIST file I have code to sort those files. The goal is to sort the files into other folders.

I understand that the first copy command should copy files from DIR to the right folder in /root/ depending on the name of the file (it should have the code from the LIST in its name)

But I have no clue for the purpose of this second copy command. Does anyone know that syntax **${i,,}** in `/bin/cp  $DIR*${i,,}* /root/$i/InvExt/` ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ```
> ${parameter^pattern}
> ${parameter^^pattern}
> ${parameter,pattern}
> ${parameter,,pattern}
> ```
>
> This expansion modifies the case of alphabetic characters in `parameter`. The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Each character in the expanded value of `parameter` is tested against `pattern`, and, if it matches the pattern, its case is converted. The pattern should not attempt to match more than one character. The `^` operator converts lowercase letters matching `pattern` to uppercase; the `,` operator converts matching uppercase letters to lowercase. The `^^` and `,,` expansions convert each matched character in the expanded value; the `^` and `,` expansions match and convert only the first character in the expanded value. If `pattern` is omitted, it is treated like a `?`, which matches every character.

So `${i,,}` expands to the value of `i` but all uppercase characters are converted to lowercase. Example:

```
$ i=CaMeL
$ echo "$i"
CaMeL
$ echo "${i,,}"
camel
$
```